# how can i use SQL subquery with django orm

Tags: mysql, django, subquery, django-orm

i want do this query for get recent avg data with django orm

```
select product_name, AVG(price) as avg_price
  from (
        select procuct_name, price, deal_date
          from deal_history
         order by deal_date desc
       ) R
```

so, i tried this orm

```
DealHistory.objects.all().order_by('-deal_date')\
           .values('product_name').annotate(avg_price=Avg('price'))
```

but this django-orm return below SQL query

```
select product_name, deal_date, avg(price) as avg_price
  from deal_history
 order by deal_date desc
 group by product_name, deal_date
```

how can i do i want

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have the Avg for all the record you have to use aggregate. annotate run for every record separately.

Comment: but i need want QuerySet not dict object...because i have more steps with this orm result

Comment: do you mean, you want to display the same Avg in every record?